# Getting and setting Cookies in PHP Curl Serverside

Tags: php, curl, oauth, php-curl

During login to an API I am receiving some server settings via CURL. I have the following script that extracts the Cookies received. I need the following Curl call to send the cookies received with the first call - somehow I cant get it working:

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init('https://www.test.com/getcookie');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
parse_str($item, $cookie);
$cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie); }

var_dump($cookies);
?>
```

After this I want to call another API service and send the cookies just received, but this does not work?

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init( 'https://test.com/api' );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token ) );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
$getbalance = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl manages cookies autonomously, you don't need to parse and set them:

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init('https://www.test.com/getcookie');

$cookiesFile = "cookies.txt"; // <--- cookies are stored here

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); // <---

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiesFile ); // <---
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $cookiesFile ); // <---

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if( $result === false ) {
    // failure
}
```

Then

```
<?php

$cookiesFile = "cookies.txt"; // <--- cookies are retrieved here

$curl = curl_init( 'https://test.com/api' );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token ) );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiesFile ); // <---
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $cookiesFile ); // <---

$getbalance = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close($curl);
```

You can specify a file where curl stores and reads cookies as in the example above.

Upon subsequent curl calls the cookies file is updated.

The cookies file doesn't need to exist prior of first call but of course PHP must have read/write access.